# Dynamic validation for lightning:input

Tags: lightning

I have an issue like i am using lightning:input which needs to take numbers. I know if i use type as number attribute then it allows user to enter only numbers. But my requirement is like user can enter anything but after pressing the button i have validate whether it is a number or not and then need to display an error message below that input field. I have used the below code but not achievable. Can someone please help on this.
Component :

```
<lightning:Input aura:id="amount" name="amount" required="true" label="Amount" messageWhenBadInput="Please enter number"></lightning:Input>
```

Controller :

```
addIncome : function(component,event,helper) {
    var incomes = component.get('v.incomes');
    var amt = component.find('amount').get('v.value');
    var inputCmp = component.find('amount');
    alert(amt);
    if(!isNaN(amt) && amt != null) {
          //mylogic
    }
    else {
        alert('Please enter valid numbers from 0-9');
        inputCmp.set('v.validity', {valid:false, badInput :true});
        //inputCmp.messageWhenTypeMismatch();
        // inputCmp.set("v.errors", [{message:"Input not a number: " }]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. I have just added inputComp.focus(); in the above line of my controller.  inputCmp.set('v.validity', {valid:false, badInput :true});

Answer (score 2):

Why not Bind, the **type** attribute of input  with a variable.

```
<aura:attribute name="fieldType" type="String" default=""/>
<aura:attribute name="fieldErrorMessage" type="String" default=""/>

<lightning:input aura:id="amount" name="amount" required="true" label="Amount" messageWhenBadInput="{!v.fieldErrorMessage}" type="{!v.fieldType}" ></lightning:Input>
```

And on button click change the value of **fieldErrorMessage** and **fieldType** which will dynamically change the type of input field and the message.

Comment: Pranay, Thanks for the response. But i do not want to specify type attribute over there. In controller i need to check and need to throw an error. As per the suggestion that you provided i understand that dynamic value of error message will be passed. But my intention is want to throw a static error message if the input is not a number.

Comment: It looks more like http://xyproblem.info/. If you dont allow your users to accept charecters why even allow them to input it.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Nice reference to xyproblem.info. +1

Answer (score 0):

please check my answer on this [Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216449/community-self-registration-make-first-name-required/216452#216452), i think it will do what you want.

in your case you have only to put my code under your field

Herr who you code should look like:

```
<aura:attribute name="showError" type="Boolean" default="false" access="private"/>
<aura:attribute name="errorMessage" type="String" access="private"/>

<lightning:Input aura:id="amount" name="amount" required="true" label="Amount" messageWhenBadInput="Please enter number"></lightning:Input>
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.showError}">
                <div id="error">
                    <ui:outputRichText value="{!v.errorMessage}"/>
                </div>
            </aura:renderIf>
```

JS: add this to you logic to show the error message you want.

```
component.set("v.showError", true);
component.set("v.errorMessage", "XYZ");
```